# Passing variables from an Ansible Playbook to Python

Tags: python, variables, ansible, environment-variables

have searched the site but have been unable to find an answer. Does anyone know how to pass variables from an Ansible playbook to python.

Here is my basic code for testing

```
---

- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    numbers:
      - 1
      - 2

  tasks:

  - name: Run Python Script
    script: pythontest.py
    register: output

  - debug: 
      var: output
```

and my basic python script

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6

print('hello world')
print(numbers)
```

Have tried numerous ways to port the variable "number" to python with no luck, does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You'll first need to modify your script to take command line arguments in the first place (cf. e.g. [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/237444)).

Comment: _Have tried numerous ways to port the variable "device" to python with no luck_ > You don't have any `device` variable, this said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you are using arg with python script, you can use only `string` args, so if you want to use list or dictionary, i suggest you to use json string:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6
import sys
import json
numbers=json.loads(sys.argv[1])
print('hello world')
print(numbers)
print(numbers[0])
```

the playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    numbers: >-
        [1,2]

  tasks:
    - name: Run Python Script
      script: pythontest.py {{numbers}}
      register: output

    - debug: 
        var: output
```

output:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "output": {
        "changed": true,
        "failed": false,
        "rc": 0,
        "stderr": "",
        "stderr_lines": [],
        "stdout": "hello world\n[1, 2]\n1\n",
        "stdout_lines": [
            "hello world",
            "[1, 2]",
            "1"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Any idea how this would work if dealing with strings as input instead of numbers?

Comment: no problem ..all is string here  when you use args  if you have a specific problem i suggest you to open a new question to avoid to pollute your first question